# Model for a cooling curve

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding how to model this through a phase shift. Essentially, I'm modelling a cooling curve through:

$$T(t)= (T_o - T_a)*e^{-kt} + T_a$$

$K$ is the gradient of the line, $T_o$ is the initial temperature and $T_a$ is the ambient temperature. Now, If I model the data from the graph, you will see there's a massive drop between $t = 8$ and $t = 10$. This is because milk is added. So, what I'm trying to do is fit a trendline to extract a formula:

[image]

[All values have ambient temperature subtracted because having the +24 screws with excel as it tries to reach this ambient temp, screwing with the trendline.]

Notice how inaccurate the exponential function is. Apparently I can use a phase shift, yet I've tried this on desmos and it hasn't helped me yet...

If I use this formula and just add +24 to every value, the data set is extremely off. For example, at $t=2$ I get 61 instead of 74.5.

So what else could I do?

Comment: Use a piecewise function.

Comment: It seems that you are using an inadequate model. The equation that you are trying to fit, does not take into account the addition of milk. What is your final goal?  How will you use the obtained model?

Comment: @user144410 The addition of the milk occurs from 8-10 minutes. The goal is to  develop an algebraic solution for the behaviour of the cooling cirve when additional cooling liquid is added.